# Regex help ^.*assets\/.*\/original.*\.*$

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to deny access to all files name original in the directory "assets/output/*/". Meaning "assets/output/3342/45.jpg" would be permitted and "assets/output/3342/orignal.jpg" would be forbidden. I've tried inserting the following into my apache2/sites-avaliable/*.conf :

```
<Directory ^.*assets\/.*\/original.*\.*$>
AllowOverride All
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Directory>
```

In addition, I've tried placing similar in a .htaccess file in /assets/. Unfortunately, I seem to have the REGEX wrong. Apparently, this works according to https://regex101.com but does not actually work in practice. Suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Why did you tag it as `.htaccess` when `Directory` is not allowed there?

Comment: I was trying different solutions using .htaccess (not the above exactly). Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Directory` or `Location` directives are not allowed in `.htaccess`. If you are on shared hosting and cannot make changes in Apache/vhost config then you can use this rule to block access to `assets/output/.*/original`

```
RewriteEngine On

# comment below line if you want to block all URIs not just existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^/?assets/output/.*/original(\..*)?$ - [F,NC]
```

Above rule will work from both Apache config and .htaccess. Prefer Apache config if you have required access.

Comment: It worked. This one was tripping me up. Thank you!  :-)

Comment: BTW for others - I placed this in /etc/apache2/sites-avaliable/*.conf and restarted server.

Answer (score 0):

You have a logical issue here. A `<Directory ...>` directive requires a *path* as argument, not a regular expression, if used the way you do. You *can* use regular expressions in such context, but then you have to *tell* the http server so by prepending it with a tilde character (`~`):

```
<Directory ~ "^/.*assets/.*/$">
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule "^/.*assets/.*/original" "-" [F]
</Directory>
```

That is documented: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory

Comment: Didn't work. I'm also thinking, I should use <Files ~ ""> instead of directory?

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I did not really look into the details. I modified the answer such that the `Directory` directive really refers to a _folder_ as it has to and then placed a `RewriteRule` inside to deny access to specific files.